# how to get all checked values in cgidview yii

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I am making a gridview in yii and my problem is that if i click select all checkbox and i go to next grid then again i click on select all after that i should get 20 values. but i am getting only 10 values which is getting from current grid. how can i get all selected checkbox value in my controller?

here is my view

```
<form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("emails/getEmails"); ?>" method="post">
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'professional-master-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search($status),
    'filter'=>$model,
        'selectableRows' => 2,
         'afterAjaxUpdate' => "function(id,data){
        $('.select-on-check').each(function(){
            if(globalselected.indexOf($(this).val()) < 0){
                $(this).prop('checked',false);
            }else{
                $(this).prop('checked',true);
            }
        });

    }",
    'beforeAjaxUpdate' => "function(id,data){
        if(typeof globalselected == 'undefined') {
            globalselected = [];
        }
        selected = $('.select-on-check:checked').map(function(i) {
               return $(this).val();
        }).get();//.join(',');
        notselected = $('.select-on-check:not(:checked)').map(function(i) {
               return $(this).val();
        }).get();//.join(',');
        for(i=0; i < selected.length; i++){
            if(globalselected.indexOf(selected[i]) < 0){
                globalselected.push(selected[i]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0; i < notselected.length; i++){
            if(globalselected.indexOf(notselected[i]) >= 0)
                globalselected.splice(globalselected.indexOf(notselected[i]), 1);
        }
    }",
    'columns'=>array(
        /*'id',*/
        array(
            'header'=>'SN.',
            'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',

            ),
             array(
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
            'selectableRows' => 2,
            'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array(
             'name' => 'nos[]','class'=>'select-on-check','id'=>'example-check-boxes',
             'type'=>'raw'   

            ),
            'value'=>'$data->id',

         ),
        array(
            'header'=>'Center name',
            'value'=>'urldecode($data->center_name)',
            'name'=>'center_name',
            'sortable'=>FALSE,
        ),
       array(
            'header'=>'Fitness Center Type',
            'value'=>'@$data->getRelated("fitnesscenter")->fitnesscenter_type',
            'name'=>'fitnesscenter',
            'sortable'=>FALSE,
        ),
        array(
            'header'=>'City',
            'value'=>'@$data->getRelated("city_id")->city_name',
            'name'=>'city_id',
            'sortable'=>FALSE,
        ),    
        array(
            'header'=>'Locality',
            'value'=>'@$data->getRelated("locality")->locality',
            'name'=>'locality',
            'sortable'=>FALSE,
        ),


    ),
)); 
?>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

this is my controller

```
var_dump($_POST['nos']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to keep selected data between pages? I personally don't like that but anyways.

I see that you did a javascript implementation that uses a variable where it keeps all the selected ids.

I can see it saves the ids before ajax updating (before changing page) and that it also restores the already selected ones when coming back to the previous page.

But you might be missing to bind a event on clicking any of the checkboxes to also add them to this javascript variable. I would put the code in `beforeAjaxUpdate` to a separate js function outside. Then call it from here and also call it in click event of every checkbox. Hmm I think with only calling it from the click event would be enough.

Also I can see that `selectableRows` is set to 2, should be removed I guess.

And finally, I would create a hidden field named `"globalselected"` and after every time you alter the `globalselected` js array I would convert it toString and put it as value of the hidden field.

Then in the controller you would look for `$_POST['globalselected']`.